# Send an Email When Tag is Applied - or When Added Automatically to a Smart Group

Tags: smartgroups, civirules, tags

I'm looking to set up a series of drip emails once a contact is tagged. Unfortunately, the rules around tagging are convoluted to the point where I'm afraid to use them since I have the potential to send an email out to many people who I don't wish to receive the email. There are also no instructions regarding how to trigger an action using tags.

Because of this, I created a rule indicating that when a contact is added to a smart group, which occurs when they are tagged, that they will receive an email. And an email is sent when I add a contact manually, but not when it is done automatically via the smart group rules.

Goal: to send a contact an email once they've been tagged.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do what you're describing using CiviRules.  However, to be safe, I would start by testing with an action other than sending email - or at least do it on a test server that redirects emails to the logs rather than sending live emails.

Here's a screenshot that shows how to set up what you're describing.  Note the trigger ("Tag added to entity") and linked condition ("Contact has tag").
[image]

Comment: I am afraid this does not work out in the way you would expect.  When a contact is tagged with 'major donor' an email is sent, as expected. But when the user adds after a while another tag (for example Non-Profit), the email is sent again. Why? The trigger fires on every tag that is added (not only Major Donor) and this contact has still the tag Major Donor.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I knew about this feature, but I couldn't experiment with it since I feared sending an email to nearly all of my contacts. I hadn't thought to conduct a different action. There also appears to be a number of (not) statements, but no instructions on how to use them.

Comment: However, if it conducts the action based on any tag being added, it effectively doesn't do the job I need it to.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the best approach, but you could probably set up a cron job with a script that checks all activities for the past 5 minutes (whatever time interval you set your cron job to run). But that approach would definitely take some scripting. I don't know of any build in options yet (though maybe someone created an extension to do something similar?).

Comment: This is interesting. I'm starting to wonder if Civi is for me. I'm good with software and have patients to work with it, but I don't know code. Hmm.

Comment: For most crm functionality, I think Civicrm is great and really easy to use. It's only when you want to do something that may not be standard that they're may be an issue. I'm a coder, so if I couldn't find an extension to add the functionality that I wanted, that would​ be my approach. There after also many people/organizations that are great at writing code, so if civicrm for most of your needs, it may be worth while to pay someone to write a customization feature for you. CiviCrm already has great notification abilities; I just don't think it has built in alerts on someone being tagged.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. This is the first CRM I've used, so it's good to know that it's functional to the point that other paid services are. Also, I'm taking your advice and am currently seeking the help of a Civi expert who also can code a solution for us. I suppose at first I didn't think it would come to that.

Comment: CiviCRM is a great CRM, so I definitely am happy to hear that you are looking into pursuing using it with paid support. I think that is the best way for first time users to get into it. Best of luck!